# Repetition via for loop based on prompt output

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, prompt, output

So essentially what I'm trying to do is to figure out how to repeat a line x number of times based on a prompt's output.

i.e

```
<script>
var favnumber = Number(prompt("What is your favorite number?"))
for(var i=0;i<favnumber;i++){
    System.out.println(name + "is bad at javascript");
}
</script>
```

any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Did you define a function `System.out.println()` somewhere? This is no native JavaScript function!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is **not** Java. So there is no function `System.out.println()` unless you define it.

To output you hav either to user the DOM, console or alert.
The later might look like this:

```
<script>
var favnumber = Number(prompt("What is your favorite number?"));
var name = 'Bob';
for(var i=0;i<favnumber;i++){
   alert(name + " is bad at javascript");
}
</script>
```

<sup>Besides, try to get used to end every command with `;`. Otherwise you run into many weird problems as a JavaScript beginner - and later as well.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not Java, so `System.out.println` doesn't have any special meaning. You have two options here: to use `console.log()`, or to use `document.write()`.

I recommend you use `console.log()`, as it doesn't mess with the current page's HTML structure:

```
var favnumber = parseInt(prompt("What is your favorite number?"), 10);
var name = 'JavaScript';

for (var i = 0; i < favnumber; i++) {
    console.log(name + ' is not Java');
}​
```

You'll need to open up your browser's JavaScript console to see those messages.

Using `document.write()` is a bit more cumbersome:

```
var favnumber = parseInt(prompt("What is your favorite number?"), 10);
var name = 'JavaScript';

for (var i = 0; i < favnumber; i++) {
    document.write(name + ' is not Java');
    document.write('<br />');
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HC3Y2/**

Comment: I'd rather not recommend starters to use `document.write`. You know the [reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1331430) for this very well but starters most likely don't.